# Laravel 5 Models/Classes not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling to use models and classes in Laravel 5 'FatalErrorException' class "name" not found.

Take the User class as standard under the App/ folder, it will only work as $user = App\User::where... or I can go 'use App/User'... Rather than just User::where. How can I get around this back to L4 where it just worked?

Secondly I came to Session::get standard Laravel Class, same error class 'Session' not found.

Unable to find a solution after 4 hours I'm resorting to asking the question... Thanks.

Comment: use namespaces, put `use Session`, `use app/models/User`

Comment: namespace doesn't forces that directory. you put that file into such folder that's why it maps the path such.

Comment: Thank you, saved me from more stress and grey hairs!

Comment: Further to this I have created a model file called Site.php which holds several classes i.e. class Testimonials extends Model {}. In a controller where I have use App/Site it won't load my Testimonial::getRandom function... says class not found!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use App\Site;

Site::all();
```

or

```
\App\Site::all();
```

Comment: I actually want to comment on this comment but I dont have enough reputation. Sorry - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192215/laravel-5-models-classes-not-found/29580552#comment46744131_29192215

Answer (score 1):

for laravel 5 you need to use namaspace
if you want to use session you need to use that line in top of the class

```
use Session;
```